# Fast Evaluation of Multiple Binomial Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, algorithms, binomial-coefficients

Suppose we have a sequence of binomial coefficients.

$$
S = \left\langle \binom{5}{2}, \binom{5}{3}, \binom{6}{3}, \binom{17}{14}, \binom{19}{15} \right\rangle
$$

How can we efficiently evaluate all of them, minimising redundant computations? In this case

$$
S = \langle 10, 10, 20, 680, 3876 \rangle.
$$

Admittedly, I do not know much about fast multipoint polynomial evaluation, but this question seems easier because it relies only on multiplicative structure (factorials). Also, I am aware of [Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem), but not sure how to effectively utilise it for this problem.

---

As a bonus question, how can we efficiently find the sum of a given sequence of binomial coefficients? Using the above example we would obtain

$$
\Sigma S = 2 \binom{6}{3} + \frac{67}{10} \binom{17}{3} = 4596.
$$

There are various identities that help in special cases, but is there a more general method?

---

If these questions are still too difficult to answer exactly, then I am also interested in efficient approximation/convergence methods.

Comment: How sparse are the values (in asymptotic terms) ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Is $x$ a satisfactory answer?

Comment: Absolutely, it dispenses me to think further.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a mathematician, but I am an experienced software engineer. I think you could use some techniques to make this evaluation faster. Here are a few tips:

### Reduce the number of multiplications

Consider the evaluation of a binomial coeficient:

$$
\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}
$$
**Slow:**
$$
\binom{17}{14} = \frac{17!}{14!\;3!} = \frac{17!}{14!\;3!} = \frac{17\cdot16\cdot15\cdot14\cdot13\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}{(14\cdot13\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1)\cdot(3\cdot2\cdot1)} = 680
$$
**Fast:**
$$
\binom{17}{14} = \binom{17}{3} = \frac{17\cdot16\cdot15}{3\cdot2\cdot1} = 680
$$
So the optimization tips are:

1. The evaluation of a binomial coefficient can be done with ($n-k$) numbers in the *numerator* and *denominator*. In the example above, we can compute $\binom{17}{14}$ with just three numbers ($n - k = 17 - 14 = 3$) in the *numerator* and *denominator*.
2. Choose the smallest *denominator* possible. As seen in the example above, $\binom{17}{14}$ = $\binom{17}{3}$. Since $3 < 14$, it is easier to compute $\binom{17}{3}$ because it will be three multiplications in the *numerator* and three in the *denominator*. In other words, the *denominator* will be $3!$ and the *numerator* will be the first $3$ terms of $17! = 17 \cdot 16 \cdot 15$.

### Cache the results

Caching the results (also called [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)) can bring significant performance improvements to your algorithm. **For each range of multiplications you have to calculate, cache the results**!

Imagine that you have to calculate $4! = 24$, so you save this information in your cache. If you then have to calculate $6!$, remember that $6! = 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4!$. There is no need to recalculate $4!$ because you already have the results.

You should also cache the result of the binomial coefficients and their complements. For example, if you calculate $\binom{17}{3}$, you should also cache $\binom{17}{14}$.